# JavaScript: Check if CTRL button was pressed

Tags: javascript

I need to check if the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> button was pressed while I am clicking on a control on my html page using JavaScript.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 154):

Try looking in the event object.

e.g.

```js
document.body.onclick = function (e) {
   if (e.ctrlKey) {
      alert("ctr key was pressed during the click");
   }
}
```

```html
<p>Click me, and sometimes hold CTRL down!</p>
```

Comment: FYI when you use this on a mac with "ctrl-click = right click" you still get the behavior of browser menu opening.

Comment: If you need to detect the Mac OS X's command key check the ```metaKey``` property of the event object ```e.metaKey```

Comment: How can you get the state of the Ctrl key being pressed or not, outside an event? The use case is setting a property of a control on asynchronous initialization depending on the state of a modifier key.

Comment: In javascript's event model you ask to check if CTRL button was down. The keypressed event is returned when a key is released again; not all browsers appear to generate such keypressed events for modifier keys like CTRL, SHIFT and others.

Answer (score 8):

Check if CTRL button was pressed.
I use this and works fine.

```
<a  href="" onclick="return Details(event)" ></a>

function Details(event) {
            if (event.ctrlKey) {
                alert('Ctrl down');
            }
}
```

Comment: What does this add to the accepted answer? How is this answer any better, or even meaningfully different?

Comment: Different requirements like what? When this page shows up in Google searches, so do *all* answers in it, not just this one. So my question still stands.

Comment: This is a helpful addition to the accepted answer because it is adding the event handler from html, not from within the javascript.

Comment: @cmyr I'd argue otherwise, setting event handlers from HTML is a security risk and should be forbidden using [CSP policies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP).

Answer (score 6):

I did it using cntrlIsPressed global flag; also takes care of select all option using Control + A

```
// Check whether control button is pressed
$(document).keydown(function(event) {
    if (event.which == "17")
        cntrlIsPressed = true;
    else if (event.which == 65 && cntrlIsPressed) {
        // Cntrl+  A
        selectAllRows();
    }
});

$(document).keyup(function() {
    cntrlIsPressed = false;
});

var cntrlIsPressed = false;
```

Comment: This is a good solution for those who want to check if CTRL is down outside of a key event handler.

Comment: introducing global state like that, is not a good idea. Why would you ever want to check for that outside of event handler?

Comment: `window.event.ctrlKey` can be used instead of this.

Comment: @galdikas: for example in the initialization of a control, you may want to set a different property if Ctrl was pressed (e.g. fine vs. coarse selection).

Comment: @MikaelDúiBolinder: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event) advises **against** using `window.event`.

Comment: @Sacky: the logic of setting `cntrlIsPressed = false;` on keyup is incorrect, because the user might press Ctrl+whatever, then release the whatever key (which will generate `keyup`), and Ctrl is still down. Also, jQuery is overkill here.

Comment: @DanDascalescu instead of `which == 17`.

Comment: Downvoted for using jQuery when not necessary. Do not use it in posts that are not tagged jQuery.