# javascript - detect ctrl key pressed or up, keypress event doesn't trigger

Tags: javascript, ctrl

I see some similar questions here (like [JavaScript: Check if CTRL button was pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6806271/javascript-check-if-ctrl-button-was-pressed)) but my problem is actually the event triggering. My js code:

```
    // Listen to keyboard. 
    window.onkeypress = listenToTheKey;
    window.onkeyup = listenToKeyUp;

    /*
        Gets the key pressed and send a request to the associated function
        @input key
    */
    function listenToTheKey(e)
    {
        if (editFlag == 0)
        {
            // If delete key is pressed calls delete
            if (e.keyCode == 46)
                deleteNode();

            // If insert key is pressed calls add blank
            if (e.keyCode == 45)
                createBlank();

            if (e.keyCode == 17)
                ctrlFlag = 1;
        }
    }
```

The event triggers for any other keys except the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>.
I need to also trigger it for <kbd>ctrl</kbd>.
I can't use jQuery/prototype/whatever so those solutions are not acceptable.

So... how can I detect the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>?

Comment: doesn't this: if (e.ctrlKey) { .... } work..?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Try using `if (e.ctrlKey)`.

[MDN: event.ctrlKey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.ctrlKey)

Answer (score 24):

Using onkeydown rather than onkeypress may help.

From http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeypress.asp

> Note: The onkeypress event is not fired for all keys (e.g. ALT, CTRL,
>   SHIFT, ESC) in all browsers. To detect only whether the user has
>   pressed a key, use the onkeydown event instead, because it works for
>   all keys.

Comment: one curiosity is that key code of `Enter` == 13, but key code of `Ctrl + Enter` == 10.

Answer (score 18):

Your event has a property named ctrlKey. You can check this to look if the key was pressed or not. See snippet below for more control like keys.

```
function detectspecialkeys(e){
    var evtobj=window.event? event : e
    if (evtobj.altKey || evtobj.ctrlKey || evtobj.shiftKey)
        alert("you pressed one of the 'Alt', 'Ctrl', or 'Shift' keys")
}
document.onkeypress=detectspecialkeys
```

Answer (score 1):

This is basically Rick Hoving's answer, but it uses `keydown` like Danielle Cerisier suggests

```js
function detectspecialkeys(e) {
  var evtobj = window.event ? event : e
  if (evtobj.ctrlKey)
    console.log("You pressed ctrl")
}
document.onkeydown = detectspecialkeys
```

Please note that you may have to click inside the preview box to focus before pressing ctrl

Comment: Just a note that `window.event` [is depreciated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event)

Comment: @JonoJob, what should be used, instead?

Comment: Oh, I guess it just means that in code that I don't want to be compatible with old stuff I can just use `e` instead of `evtobj`.