# jQuery keypress doesn't detect CTRL + V

Tags: javascript, jquery

The keypress doesn't detect `CTRL + V` when pressed on the text box. I have seen a similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9374915/javascript-detect-ctrl-key-pressed-or-up-keypress-event-doest-trigger) to mine. But we have different implementation. I want to trigger an ajax request if the user idle in typing for 1.5 sec.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $(document).on('keypress', '#subject-name', function() {
        updateTimeOut( this, checkSubject );
    });   
});
```

The method `updateTimeOut()` is something like this:

```
var updateTimeOut = function( textBoxObject, ajaxCall ) {
                         if (timeoutReference) clearTimeout(timeoutReference);
                         timeoutReference = setTimeout(function() {
                                doneTyping.call( textBoxObject, ajaxCall );
                         }, 1500);
                    };
```

My question is. Is't better to use `change` is the best for my task? Does `change` can also do check with interval?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you want to know when the values changes, no matter how it happens, keypress or not (e.g. right click text box and left click paste).

This should work for you

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('input', '#subject-name', function() {
        updateTimeOut(this, checkSubject);
    });   
});
```

FYI, `$(function() {})` is shorthand for `$(document).ready(function() {})`.

Comment: The textbox is dynamically generated by `bootstrap`. Can I bind an event with that?

Comment: I see. After some research I found out that `change` event triggers only after you focus out the textbox. What should I use if I need something like all changes including when typing?

Comment: Some more research turned up the `input` event on modern browsers (not IE 8 or less).

Comment: I didn't catch that. What do you mean turned up?