# Detecting a key press ignoring modifier keys

Tags: javascript

I am implementing an idle timeout functionality for my website. I want to reset the idle timeout whenever the user interacts with the page, which I want to implement as "the user clicks anywhere on the page" or "the user types a key".

The following code works:

```
window.addEventListener('click', resetTimeout);
window.addEventListener('keydown', resetTimeout);
```

Unfortunately it detects modifier keys (alt, shift, ctrl, meta). I don't want to reset the timeout in these cases. For example, when the user alt+tab's to another window, the alt key resets the timeout.

An alternative to `keydown` is `keypress`, however, it is [marked as deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keypress_event). Is there an alternative for `keypress`, specifically for the situation I am describing?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9374915/javascript-detect-ctrl-key-pressed-or-up-keypress-event-doesnt-trigger). Add some conditions in resetTimeout function.

Comment: How can it detect `alt` if `keydown` as they are different events

Comment: You can detect event type. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/type.

Comment: Conditions like "ignore if `e.shiftKey`" do not work, as it will also ignore, e.g., shift+a.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**note** to excludedKeys you can add all keys you don't want. You can search for them here: https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents-key/

```
let excludedKeys = ["Alt"];
window.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
  if(!excludedKeys.includes(e.key)) resetTimeout();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I came here looking for an answer but was not happy with having to maintain a list of exclusions so I solved this by checking the length of the key name.

```js
window.addEventListener('keydown', resetTimeout);

function resetTimeout(args) {
    if (args.key.length === 1) {
        // 'a', 'A', '1', '.', '%' etc
    } else {
        // 'Alt', 'Control', 'Shift', 'Escape', 'Backspace' etc
    }
}
```

You can also use the next trick to isolate modifier keys from any other key. Thanks to @mikeypie for the suggestion.

```js
function resetTimeout(args) {
    if (args.key.length === 1 && args.key === args.code) {
        // 'a', 'A', '1', '.', '%', 'Escape', 'Backspace' etc
    } else {
        // 'Alt', 'Control', 'Shift'
    }
}
```

This works because the `args.key` includes `Left` or `Right` for modifier keys, e.g. `args.key` contains `LeftShift` while `args.code` contains just `Shift`.

Comment: To include 'Backspace' and 'Escape' (etc) but not 'Alt' or 'Control' (etc), you might use `args.key.length === 1 && args.key === args.code`. This works because modifiers like 'Alt' include 'Left' or 'Right' in their args.key but not in their args.code, but action keys seem to all match exactly.

Comment: Should this be an `||`? It doesn't seem to work with an `&&`.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need a variable to keep a true/false which tells you whether an ignored key is being held down, and if it is, then you can ignore all keydown events which would reset your timer. When your ignored key is released, you can then listen for keydown events.

Here is a small demo:

```js
const display = document.getElementById('status');

let idleTime = 0;
const timer_cb = _ => {
  if(idleTime > 5) {
    display.innerText = "You are now idle";
    clearInterval(timer);
  } else {
    display.innerText = "You have been inactive for: " + idleTime +" seconds";
    idleTime++;
  }
}

let timer = setInterval(timer_cb, 1000);

const ignoreKeys = new Set(['Meta', 'Control', 'Shift', 'Alt']);
let ignore = false;

const resetTimeout = ({key}) => {
  ignore = ignore || ignoreKeys.has(key);
  if(!ignore) {
    idleTime = 0;
    timer_cb();
    clearInterval(timer);
    timer = setInterval(timer_cb, 1000);
  }
};

const acknowledge = ({key}) => {
  ignore = !!(ignore ^ ignoreKeys.has(key));
}

window.addEventListener('click', resetTimeout);
window.addEventListener('keydown', resetTimeout);
window.addEventListener('keyup', acknowledge);
timer_cb();
```

```html
<span id="status"></span>
```

Comment: That solution also ignores, e.g., 'Shift+A', which is a legitimate key to reset the timeout. I guess just having the `ignoreKeys` array and checking for it works (without the `ignore` state). I'm just surprised how expensive all these solutions are compared to what `onkeypress` had to offer, without ANY additional work.

Answer (score -2):

Add function and check for the command keys as follow:

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const key = event.keyCode; //You can also use event.key to get the text value. e.g. "Alt", "Ctrl"
  if(key != 17 && key != 18) //Alt and Ctrl keys. key should not 17 as well as 18 then resetTimeOut.
  {
       resetTimeout();
  }
});
```

If you want to use .key then you can use string and check the pressed key is present in that string or not.

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      const key = event.key
      if(! "Alt,Control,Tab".split(",").includes(key))
      {
           resetTimeout();
      }
    });
```

Comment: `event.keyCode` is deprecated as well.

Comment: is event.key available?

Comment: It is, but I was trying to avoid enumerating all `LeftShift`, `RightShift`, `LeftCtrl`, etc.

Comment: @crazypeter You could use `'LeftShift RightShift LeftCtrl (etc)'.split(' ').includes(event.key)`

Comment: That seems fairly expensive given this is executed on every keypress. But I guess `event.key` only has four relevant values, `Shift`, `Alt`, `Ctrl` and `Meta`.