# detecting ctrl+tab key press in javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, onkeypress

I have a requirement wherein I must restrict the user viewing my web page. Users should not be allowed to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> before finishing a task in the page.

Is there a way to detect <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> keypress in javascript/jQuery?

Comment: Read this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6806271/javascript-check-if-ctrl-button-was-pressed

Comment: 1) What would you think if a webpage would restrict you as user? 2) Do you think Browser-Vendors would let a webpage manipulate the browser in such a way? 3) Answer your question yourself. 4) Go to your boss/customer and tell them it's not possible and altogether makes no sense and it's a big security issue.

Comment: @Christoph Not Security but Usability issue.

Comment: @Christoph: Or in short, what can be used can also be abused/misused.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This code will detect CTRL+Tab:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.ctrlKey && e.which == 9) {
        alert("CTRL + TAB Pressed")
    }
})
```

Note however that CTRL+Tab functionality is controlled by the browser and you cannot stop it as this fiddle will demonstrate if you have more than one tab open:

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hBfCG/)

Comment: Note that this does NOT work, in recent versions of either Firefox or Chrome. (Firefox 68 and Chrome 76, to be precise, and only tested on Linux).
There is no keydown event triggered when you press tab, while holding ctrl down. I imagine it is a deliberate security thing, to prevent clever spoofing attacks?

Comment: That sounds likely. Note this is a nearly 7 year old answer. I'll investigate and update with findings

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot. That is, you can detect the keystroke, but not block the behaviour of toggling tabs. And fortunate too, because websites that do this would make browsing a real pain.

And it would defeat the purpose of a web browser. If you need restrictions like that, don't build a website, but a desktop application. But rather, if you build a browser application, make it smart enough to save its state, so users can come back to a task and finish it later if they have switched to a different tab first.

Comment: Restricting users to go to another page is typical old-fashened application behaviour. If you want to build your app in the browser you'll have to work around some of the liberties the user has. Instead of requiring them to finish a task before moving to another tab, make it so that they can re-open and finish the task later. Besides, even if you can capture this keystroke (apparently you can detect it at least), users have other ways to change tabs as well. You can't or shouldn't restrict users like this.

Answer (score 0):

Check the ctrlKey property on the event in your handler.

```
$(document).on('keypress','*',function(e){alert(e.ctrlKey);})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kDdzj/

You can detect it, but you can't stop it.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan The tab key is just a regular keycode. You'd detect it as you would any other keypress, by checking the `keyCode` property.