# Multi-select using 'ctrl' key in full-calendar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fullcalendar

I am using full-calendar to achieve multi-select dates and add some text on selected text, I am using 'selectable' feature but for some reason when I click 'ctrl' key, I am not getting any callback. 
My goal is as a user I should be able to select multiple dates using ctrl and shift key.
should be able to select/unselect the same day.[image: Press control and select multiple date]
[image: Press shift and select range of date]

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/select-method.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6806271/javascript-check-if-ctrl-button-was-pressed.

you can check if ctrl is pressed and select.

Comment: @MadhawaPriyashantha, I know I can check the CTRL, but issue is fullcalendar library is returning false or preventing click after CTRL press.

Comment: Did you ever find out how to do that ? Because I have exactly the same problem :/

Comment: @stadja I was not able to do it, so I am using ALT key instead of CTRL.

Comment: Yes right now it's not possible... but once this pull request will be merged it should work:
https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/pull/4385

Comment: finally merged the above pull request manually to give a temporary fix and it's working.